# Reverse Engineer a speaker crossover

Tags: audio, bluetooth, speakers

I'm interested in building a portable bluetooth boombox, but I don't really know anything about audio.  I am going to follow this forum (http://techtalk.parts-express.com/forum/speaker-project-gallery/62234-1st-boombox-project-the-madeleine?242898-1st-Boombox-Project-The-Madeleine=) for the build, which I can easily follow except for one part.

The guide gets kind of vague when he starts to talk about the audio crossover design, but there are some pictures he includes of the PCB and parts.

[image]

[image: Inputs]

[image: PCB assembled]

My question is: Is my below schematic correct?  The connections in red are directly from the first picture of the physical PCB, but the blue connections are what I'm unsure of.

[image: Schematic]
If you need any additional information like speaker frequencies or PCB component values please let me know.  Thank you.

UPDATE:
I've found a picture of the bottom after scouring online for a while.  I've posted an updated schematic with what I think is accurate based on the pictures.  Do you think this is indeed a correct schematic?

[image: PCB top]
[image: PCB bottom]
[image: New schematic]

Comment: Reverse Engineers would include the P/N of each cap and confirm if non-polarized with LCR readings with a schematic using proper symbols.

Comment: Redraw your schematic properly with all part numbers and values shown. The connections to Tweet- and Tweet+ appear to be reversed (R1 and R2 go to J1 pin 6, not pin 5).

Comment: My apologies, I've updated the schematic :)

Comment: Okay, to the best of my knowledge, my most recent schematic is the proper layout (unless someone objects of course :) ).

Comment: I beleive this is not "reverse engineerng"... but I might be wrong... still, this is an interesting post!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked your link, but stopped reading when I reached a picture of the bass reflex vents. They are way too long. Also the drivers look very expensive. But it will sound like crap because the vents are way too long, so they will resonate like organ pipes. This hints at the designer having no clue what he's doing.

I'd advise building the classic:

http://www.diyaudio.com/forums/class-d/104402-boominator-stab-ultimate-party-machine.html

Comment: They'd be quite useful for storing pencils in though.

Comment: Wow, very active forum post!  Thanks!  I'll definitely be looking into this...